# Cobol: Is there a way to output the names of Copybook-fields as headers

Tags: cobol, mainframe

We are about to convert datasets on a Mainframe to CSV format. The data fields are stored in copybooks, I would like to know if it's possible to output the names of the fields (not the values) one after the other for a header. it would be good if there was an automated Solution, because there are about 100 tables with 15< fields. For example:

```
 01   TABLE1.                       
   05   FIELDA         PIC X(1)  .
   05   FIELDB         PIC X(7)  .
   05   FIELDC         PIC X(6)  .
   05   FIELDD         PIC X(4)  .
   05   FIELDE         PIC X(4)  .
   05   FIELDF         PIC X(2)  .
```

What i want to have now is like:

```
FIELDA;FIELDB;FIELDC;FIELDD;FIELDE;FIELDF
```

It would be great if the Solution would be written in COBOL :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `GENERATE JSON` is likely your best approach.

Comment: I've tried to solve it with a REXX exec call but I would like to have a more simple method. Never done something with JSON on mainframe, will try it, thx :)